# Capturing blocks from method parameters in Kiwi?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, kiwi

I'm working with the [Firebase iOS SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/), and I'm struggling to figure out how to fully-test some of the Firebase method calls using Kiwi.

I'm using an instance of Firebase to "watch" a path:

`Firebase *streamsReference = [self.firebaseRef childByAppendingPath:@"streams"];`

And then using that `streamsReference` to observe events:

```
[streamsReference observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    // do stuff in the block here

}];
```

I want to test the effects of the code in the block.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    it(@"should handle incoming connections as a hook for WebRTC", ^{

        id mockFirebaseClass = [KWMock mockForClass:[Firebase class]];

        // mock Firebase object to handle "/streams" path
        id mockFirebaseStreamsReference = [KWMock mockForClass:[Firebase class]];

        // return the streams reference object via the mock Firebase object
        [mockFirebaseClass stub:@selector(childByAppendingPath:) andReturn:mockFirebaseStreamsReference];

        // attempt to capture the block in the second param
        KWCaptureSpy *spy = [mockFirebaseStreamsReference captureArgument:@selector(observeEventType:withBlock:) atIndex:1];

        // inject the Firebase mock into the test class
        classUnderTest.firebaseRef = mockFirebaseClass;

        // capture the block from the spy
        void(^blockToRun)() = spy.argument;

        // call method that will invoke the Firebase observeEventType:withBlock method
        [classUnderTest setupIncomingRemoteConnectionHandler];

        //  run the captured block
        blockToRun(nil);

        ...
        ... expectations go here
        ...

    });
```

When I run the test, it's failing with an `Argument requested has yet to be captured` error - which suggests that I'm nailing things up in the wrong order. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to capture the argument too early, before the watched method had been called. Try to move the `void(^blockToRun)() = spy.argument;` line after the call to `setupIncomingRemoteConnectionHandler`. If that doesn't work either, it means that you need make run some extra calls to your test class in order to trigger the `observeEventType:withBlock:` call.